# What to do if Professor offers an internship position

Tags: communication, internship

I had been offered a position to work as a intern in one of my professor's lab. He had asked me if I would be interested. But the position was not confirmed. How do I ask him about the confirmation? Would it seem desperate? I really enjoy the course and would love to contribute to the work that is being undertaken.

Comment: How long ago was this conversation? What is the time when your potential internship would start?

Comment: He asked me two weeks ago. The internship should start in coming summer.

Comment: OK, no need to worry about seeming desperate then, and there's no hurry either. Maybe ask for "what would be the next steps" or "what's the procedure for becoming an intern" instead of just for confirmation, that's likely to get you a better understanding of what will happen next.

Answer (score 3):

Then ask him, either when you happen to meet in the corridor or a nice email - he may be waiting on you...

I don't think he will run around looking for you.

But think of the difference between "desperate" and "motivated" - he will be happy / pleased to find someone motivated !